# Entity Framework EdmFunction import is not recognized

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

First of all, I had a previous question some time before, which, although seems very similar, is NOT the same problem, have a look at it: [Function import from SQL Server to Entity Framework runtime exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884558/function-import-from-sql-server-to-entity-framework-runtime-exception)

This function, HammingDistance, used to work well after creating the scalar function in SQL Server, and then imported into the Entity Framework using the EDM function mapping. I kept building my site, made some differences around the site and the EDMX, but haven't touched the function and kept it safe. Here is the SQL function at the SQL Server:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[HammingDistance]
(@first bigint, @second bigint) returns int
as
begin
    declare @xor bigint = @first ^ @second;
    declare @one bigint = 1;
    declare @diff int = 0;
    declare @and bigint;
    while (@xor != 0)
        begin
        set @and = @xor & @one;
        if(@and = @one)
            begin
            set @diff = @diff + 1;
            end
        set @xor = @xor / 2;
        end
    return @diff;
end
```

And here is my C# code:

Declaration:

```
public static class EdmFunctionMapping
{

    [EdmFunction("MainDB.Store", "HammingDistance")]
    public static int GetHammingDistance(long hash1, long hash2)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method can only be used in a LINQ-to-Entities query");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var query = (from p in VisibleObjects.OfType<Photo>()
                     let hd = EdmFunctionMapping.GetHammingDistance(targetPhoto.Analysis.Hash, p.Analysis.Hash)
                     let cd = Math.Abs(targetPhoto.Analysis.High.Red - p.Analysis.High.Red)+
                     Math.Abs(targetPhoto.Analysis.High.Green - p.Analysis.High.Green)+
                     Math.Abs(targetPhoto.Analysis.High.Blue - p.Analysis.High.Blue) +
                     Math.Abs(targetPhoto.Analysis.Low.Red - p.Analysis.Low.Red) +
                     Math.Abs(targetPhoto.Analysis.Low.Green - p.Analysis.Low.Green) +
                     Math.Abs(targetPhoto.Analysis.Low.Blue - p.Analysis.Low.Blue)
                     where
                     hd < 5 ||
                     (hd < 15 || cd < 100)
                     orderby hd ascending
                     select p).Take(50);
        return query.ToList();
```

where VisibleObjects does not evaluate the Enumerable. Here it is anyway:

```
static IEnumerable<GlobalObject> VisibleObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return from obj in db.GlobalObjectSet where obj.IsVisible && !obj.SiteUser.IsDeactivated orderby obj.ID descending select obj;
        }
    }
```

Everything used to work about two or three weeks ago, and in that interval I've added/removed lots of things and did not check if Hamming Distance worked or not, so I can't tell anything about when it broke. It doesn't work anymore, it's just like EdmFunction attribute is not there, trying to evaluate in my application and throwing up the exception I wrote saying that it could only be used in an L2E query. I've double checked everything, even re-created the database completely and generated from EDMX, and created and imported the function using Update Model from Database, and it sees the function in EDMX, and it is available (obviously) in the EDMX file SSDL section such as:

```
    <Function Name="HammingDistance" ReturnType="int" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
      <Parameter Name="first" Type="bigint" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="second" Type="bigint" Mode="In" />
    </Function>
```

But when it comes to the app, it just won't map to EDM! Tried several times, creating all the database from scratch, nothing changes, it throws the exception in `query.ToList()`, and there's no inner exception (it makes sense as it's throwing my own exception, which, should NOT be executed by the app). I have no idea of the source of the problem, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't recognize your Edm mapped function make sure that you didn't accidentally change the query to linq-to-objects somewhere because that is exactly the reason why you can see that error. To validate that, simply try to create another test query which will do just direct entity access and call your function. Something like:

```
long hash = targetPhoto.Analysis.Hash;
var query = from p in db.GlobalObjectSet.OfType<Photo>()
            select new { EdmFunctionMapping.GetHammingDistance(hash, p.Analysis.Hash) };
```

If such query passes you have definitely problem I mentioned.

**Edit:**

I think I see the problem now. Your `VisibleObjects` returns `IEnumerable` => linq-to-objects. Try this instead:

```
public static IQueryable<GlobalObject> GetVisibleObjects(this IQueryable<GlobalObject> query) 
{
    return from obj in query 
           where obj.IsVisible && 
                 !obj.SiteUser.IsDeactivated 
           orderby obj.ID descending 
           select obj;
}
```

And call your method like:

```
from p in db.GlobalObjectSet.GetVisibleObjects().OfType<Photo>() ...
```

Comment: yep, using a simple query such as `var query = from p in db.GlobalObjectSet.OfType<Photo>() where EdmFunctionMapping.GetHammingDistance(p.Analysis.Hash, targetPhoto.Analysis.Hash) < 5 select p;` worked. so where could be the problem then?  the methods I'm using is all that I've posted up there, only regular math functions, VisibleObjects (which I've also posted), and GetHammingDistance (which doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem now..).

Comment: I added some more info. Your query is linq-to-objects.

Comment: yes, I've just figured out now, and haven't realized that I was using IEnumerable instead of IQueryable as my dataset wasn't big(not affecting performance) and HammingDistance was the only function that I rely on SQL Server itself.. changed it to IQueryable and it worked.